# can't quote ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following index action in controller

```
  def index
    details = CustomerInfo.current
                          .for_user(params[:user])
                          .for_product(params[:product])
                          .for_area(params[:area])
                          .where(value: params.permit(:value))
    render(json: details)
  end
```

When i added permit in `where` i started getting the error `can't quote ActionController::Parameters` at `render(json: details)`
But if i not use permit `.where(value: params[:value])` it works fine.

Comment: Maybe the params[:value] is serialized data?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are using permit as it's intended to be used.

`params.permit` returns an instance of `ActionController::Parameters`, hence the error you get. See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c1014e435d26db867b2c15b74c9ef47ccff38edb/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L522) for the code.

`permit` should be used to limit the attributes that can be updated through mass assignment.

Here's the relevant documentation for it: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/permit
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters